# Should each Django app have its own server instance?

Tags: python, django

I am just starting out on Django. I have successfully set it up and have it it talking to mysql and am ready to code . Inside of the eclipse IDE; should each app you are working have its own distinct server ( i.e my site) instance?   Does it matter ?

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean by "own distinct server"? Usually server refers to deployment.

Answer (score 0):

generally each of your django PROJECTS (`django-admin startproject`) has its own server, project is the directory containing all your apps and contains the `manage.py`.  each app ususally doesn't because a project is composed of apps.

For developing django includes a development server you can run using `runserver`

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`